# AWS RDS SESSION vs. GLOBAL sql modes SETTING values

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, amazon-rds, sql-mode

I have installed a new AWS RDS MariaDB, imported all my tables and it's up and running. In my old DB I did not have `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` set so I have to go through all my tables and modify the columns to specify null values. Until then I want to disable `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` for now so I can test things and later I can add it back.

I was able to modify the `@@SESSION` SQL mode just fine but I am still not able to insert records because some of the inserts are null so I am assuming the `@@GLOBAL` is still superseding the `@@SESSION` SQL modes.

I am using MySQL Workbench to access my RDS and when I try and use `SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';` but I get `Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation`.

Is there any way for me to modify the `@@GLOBAL` SQL mode with AWS RDS and am I correct that `@@GLOBAL` is superseding `@@SESSION` SQL mode?

**UPDATE**

I have been able to get around this executing this query whenever a connection is made to my DB, but is there a more permanent way of doing this?

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set permanent `sql_mode` by accessing your AWS dashboard > RDS > Parameter groups > sql_mode

And just save the values you need. Make sure the parameter groups you changed belong to the right RDS.

[image]